# Reconnection in Elasticsearch Cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, cluster-computing

I have a question about the clustering respectively the reconnection in the clustering in Elasticsearch.

I have 2 Elasticsearch-Server on 2 different servers within a network. Both Elasticsearch's are in the same cluster.
In an error scenario the network connection could be broken. I simulate this behaviour while pulling the network cable on one server.
After reconnecting the server to the network the clustering won't be working. When I put some data to one Elasticsearch, the data would not be transferred to the other Elasticsearch.

Does anybody know if there are some settings about the reconnecting?

Best Regards
  Thomas

Answer (score 0):

Why dont just put all Elasticsearch servers behind the load balancer with single DNS name, there could be issue in server which go down and need manual intervention , after correcting problem in server it will be available under load balancer automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if all nodes join the cluster again?

You may want to try following APIs:

Check nodes status
http://es-host:9200/_nodes

Check cluster status
http://es-host:9200/_cluster/health

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.